# SVG does not align the same on Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I am playing around with designing a test logo for a client I made in Inkscape. The issue I am having is that the SVG file displays differently whether it is in Chrome or Firefox. Firefox shows the SVG correctly. The way I check is to simply open the svg with each browser.

Firefox:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejJzn.png)
The underline below the two ps is correct.

Chrome: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDNHi.png) 
The underline has been shifted to the right a bit, but I have no idea why?

If anyone could help me with this, it would be much appreciated

For reference, here is the SVG code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="32.922401mm"
   height="17.210264mm"
   viewBox="0 0 32.922398 17.210266"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   sodipodi:docname="logo.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11)">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="1.4"
     inkscape:cx="-110.02828"
     inkscape:cy="38.099691"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="g1103"
     showgrid="false"
     fit-margin-top="0.9"
     fit-margin-left="1.7"
     fit-margin-right="1.7"
     fit-margin-bottom="0.9"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1012"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="0"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-40.131929,-66.661274)">
    <g
       id="g1103">
      <path
         sodipodi:nodetypes="cc"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         id="path1067"
         d="m 54.649326,79.090727 c 5.3644,7.743137 9.52043,-0.01667 9.53666,-0.04678"
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#00d1b2;stroke-width:0.89522964;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" />
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:10.58333302px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
         x="40.934826"
         y="75.066071"
         id="text830"><tspan
           sodipodi:role="line"
           id="tspan828"
           x="40.934826"
           y="75.066071"
           style="font-size:9.87777805px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1"><tspan
             style="font-size:9.87777805px;fill:#00d1b2;fill-opacity:1"
             id="tspan832"><tspan
   style="fill:#001eb2;fill-opacity:1"
   id="tspan817">pu</tspan>pp</tspan><tspan
             style="fill:#ff59ff;fill-opacity:1"
             id="tspan819">y</tspan></tspan></text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I created a demo on https://js-9hqdrf.stackblitz.io and did not notice a difference between Chrome and Firefox. The one thing I noticed from the screenshots is that the letter spacing looks a little different. You could try converting the text to outlines, that way you don't have to deal with the font.

Comment: Instead of nesting `<tspan>`s try putting them one next yo another

Comment: thanks I took your stackblitz and extracted the html. For some reason that works perfectly fine. I will use that as the template and take a look as to why there was a difference on my computer. Thank you!